# Exist $f\colon\mathbb R\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ is a monotonic, non-constant and periodic function of period $T>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, periodic-functions

**Question**

> Say whether it is true or false that exist $f\colon\mathbb R\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ is a monotonic, non-constant and periodic function of period $T>0$ ?

Comment: Periodic means it repeats. Monotone means it is an increasing function or a decreasing function. How can a function be monotone and periodic at the same time, and not be a constant?

Comment: If we take the hypothesis that the domain is $\mathbb R$, take the function $\tan $

Comment: @CPMP $\tan$ is neither monotone nor defined over the whole of $\Bbb R$. Perhaps you mean, monotone *within the period*.

Comment: The $\tan$ function is not monotone. Clearly, $\tan(\pi/4) > tan(3\pi/4)$, hence the function is decreasing. An increasing function is one where $f(x)\le f(y)$ for any $x\le y$.

Comment: $\tan$ is monotone on this domain

Comment: $\tan(\pi/8)<\tan(\pi/4)>\tan(5\pi/8)$ it is not monotone in either direction

Comment: @FShrike You're right, I was thinking about monotony within the period. Tks for help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is increasing and has period $T$. Take any $x\in\mathbb R$, then $f(x) = f(x+T)$ implies $f$ is constant on $[x,x+T]$ due to monotonicity. So $f$ must be constant. Hence,

> if $f\colon\mathbb R\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ is a monotonic, non-constant, periodic function of period $T>0$, then $f$ is continuous

is vacuously true.

Comment: What answer is detailed that if $f$ is monotonous and then there isn't even one as an answer to my question, I'll edit it for better clarification

Answer (score 1):

> a monotonic, non-constant, periodic function of period $T>0$, then $f$ is continuous.

It's a vacuous statement:

If $f$ is non-constant, then there are numbers $x$ and $y$ such that  $$y>x \quad\text{ and } \quad f(y)\neq f(x)$$

Now $f$ is periodic, i.e. there exists $x'>y$ such that $f(x')=f(x)$
and hence:

- If $f(y) > f(x) = f(x')$ then $f$ is not monotonic.
- If $f(y) < f(x) = f(x')$ then $f$ is not monotonic, either.

Thus no such function exists, thus every such function is constant :-)